# Função date do PHP está retornando o dia no lugar do mês

Tags: php, data

Preciso formatar a data recebida de um `$_POST` da seguinte forma:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['data'])); ///O POST está enviando 10/05/2019 << Dia/Mês/Ano.
```

Mas o retorno dessa função que era pra ser `2019-05-10`, não está retornando isso.

Essa função está retornando `2019-10-05`, ou seja, o valor do **dia** está no lugar do valor do **mês** (Ano-Dia-Mês).

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php), quando a string está no formado "xx/yy/zzzz", ela é interpretada como "mês/dia/ano".

Uma opção para resolver isso é usar [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) para fazer o *parsing* (indicando o formato em que a string está), e em seguida [`format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) para converter a data para o formato desejado:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '10/05/2019');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d'); // 2019-05-10
```

Ou, se preferir no estilo procedural:

```
$d = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', '10/05/2019');
echo date_format($d, 'Y-m-d'); // 2019-05-10
```

---

A mesma [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) ainda mostra outros formatos que são interpretados como "dia mês ano", como quando é usado hífen ou ponto como separador. Então bastaria fazer um *replace*, trocando a barra por um desses separadores:

```
$data = '10/05/2019';
// trocar barra por hífen
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(preg_replace('{/}', '-', $data)));
// trocar barra por ponto
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(preg_replace('{/}', '.', $data)));
```

Ambos imprimem `2019-05-10`.

---

A função [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) exige uma regex no primeiro parâmetro (por isso a barra é escrita como `{/}`). Mas nesse caso, como a substituição é mais simples, você pode usar simplesmente [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$data = '10/05/2019';
// trocar barra por hífen
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data)));
// trocar barra por ponto
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '.', $data)));
```

Comment: Obrigado Valeu!