# Converter semana do ano, dia da semana e ano em data

Tags: php, data

Estou montando um calendário e estou a procura de uma maneira de converter a partir do número da semana do ano junto com o número do dia da semana e o ano em data, por exemplo:

```
$hoje = date('d/m/Y'); 
    $sem_ano = date('W', strtotime($hoje));
    $dia_sem = date('N', strtotime($hoje));
    $ano = date('Y', strtotime($hoje));
```

Para essa data, `$sem_ano`, retorna 32, `$dia_sem` retorna 4 (por ser quinta feira) e `$ano`, 2019. A partir desses dados, gostaria que ele me retornasse a data relativo a 'N' = 1 (segunda-feira), é possível?

---

Deixando um pouco mais claro: a partir da semana do ano e o ano, preciso que ele me retorne uma data que pertença a esta semana, exemplo xx/08/2019.

Comment: Se você entra com o valor de `N`, quinta-feira, por que quer que retorne o valor de `N`, segunda-feira?

Comment: porque ele tem que pegar a data a partir de hoje, o hoje é variável

Comment: preciso que ele retorne uma data relativa ao primeiro dia da semana 32, para que eu possa completar a tabela, nao precisa utilizar necessariamente o N, eu utilizo ele pra referenciar o local onde ficara o $hoje

Comment: Um detalhe: sua variável `$hoje` contém uma string com a data no formato 'dd/mm/yyyy'. Mas quando a string está nesse formato, `strtotime` interpreta como "mês/dia/ano" ([leia aqui para mais detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/383060/112052)). Hoje não dá problema porque é 08/08, mas [em qualquer outro dia dará](https://ideone.com/fUouaj). De qualquer forma, se quer a data atual, basta fazer `date('W')`, `date('N')', etc. (ou use `strtotime('now')`)

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy nao é dia mes e ano?? li em algum lugar que o date('N'... precisa deste formato para retornar o valor da semana

Comment: Ainda não ficou muito claro. Se vc recebe o ano e a semana (por exemplo, semana 32 de 2019), vc quer somente a segunda-feira referente a esta semana? Ou quer todas as 7 datas que pertencem a esta semana? Ah, sim, vc também deve definir qual a definição de semana vai usar (o primeiro dia da semana varia conforme aspectos culturais, religiosos, etc - em alguns países é segunda, em outros é domingo, etc - veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/399758/112052))

Comment: conforme a documentação do PHP (https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) , N utiliza-se o primeiro dia da semana como valor "1" para segunda feira, eu quero somente o primeiro dia, depois ele completa automaticamente com um while, que ai é outra historia.. só preciso desta data "xx/08/2019" que eu ja vou conseguir trabalhar com ele para chegar nos outros dias da semana

Comment: mais uma tentativa de esclarecer.. concorda comigo que a semana 32 está dentro do mes 8? então queria saber como encontrar isso com boas práticas e não com gambiarra, o ano eu ja retorno a partir do $hoje, com isso ja consigo montar xx/08/2019.. ficou mais claro?

Comment: Coloque na pergunta que você quer calcular o número de semanas decorrida desde determinada data, pois se não fosse seu último comentário teria dado um voto para fechar a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tem o ano e o número da semana, e quer uma data correspondente a esta semana, basta usar [`DateTime::setISODate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php):

```
$ano = 2019;
$semana = 32;
$d = new DateTime();
$d->setISODate($ano, $semana);
echo $d->format('d/m/Y');
```

No caso, ele seta a data para o primeiro dia da referida semana. Como é usada a definição da [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (na qual a segunda-feira é o primeiro dia da semana), o resultado será **05/08/2019**.

Opcionalmente, você pode obter outros dias desta semana. Por exemplo, se quiser o segundo dia desta semana (a terça-feira da 32ª semana de 2019, ou seja, 06/08/2019), basta fazer:

```
$d->setISODate($ano, $semana, 2); // 06/08/2019
```

---

Só lembrando que essa forma de trabalhar com "semanas do ano" pode ter alguns resultados "estranhos" e contra-intuitivos na primeira e última semana no ano.

Por exemplo, se considerarmos o final de 2018 e início de 2019:

```
Dom Seg Ter Qua Qui Sex Sab
 23  24  25  26  27  28  29  <-- dez/2018
 30  31   1   2   3   4   5  <-- dez/2018 e jan/2019
  6   7   8   9  10  11  12  <-- jan/2019
```

Se quisermos a segunda-feira da primeira semana de 2019 (`$d->setISODate(2019, 1, 1)`), o resultado será **31/12/2018**. Sim, [segundo a ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) a primeira semana de um ano é o período de 7 dias que começa em uma segunda-feira **e** tem pelo menos 4 dias naquele ano. Sendo assim, a primeira semana de 2019 começa em 31/12/2018 e termina em 06/01/2019.

**Atenção**: esse "ano" é chamado de "*week based year*" (ou simplesmente [*week year*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)), e é um campo diferente do "ano calendário" (31/12/2018 está no "ano calendário" de 2018, mas o seu *week based year* é 2019). Muita atenção, porque o valor do ano que `setISODate` recebe é o *week based year* (para a maior parte do ano, esse valor é o mesmo do "ano calendário", mas para o final de dezembro e início de janeiro, [podem haver essas diferenças](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/399758/112052)).

---

Para saber o *week based year* de uma data, use o formato `o`. Veja a diferença para o "ano calendário":

```
$d = new DateTime();
$d->setISODate(2019, 1, 1);
echo $d->format('d/m/Y o'); // 31/12/2018 2019
```