# Subtrair 1 mes em uma data em PHP

Tags: php

Como reduzir 1 mes em uma data em PHP? Estou tentar utilizar desse modo mas estou recebendo uma data incorreta

```
$dtini = '16/09/2019';

echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-1 month', strtotime($dtini)));
```

Resultado = 01/12/1969

O que está errado ?

Comment: `dd/mm/yyyy` é um formato válido para a função `strtotime`?

Comment: Basicamente, `strtotime` interpreta o formato `16/09/2019` como "mês/dia/ano", e como 16 não é um mês válido, ele retorna `FALSE`, que é convertido para o número zero, que `date` interpreta como 1 de janeiro de 1970 (e ao subtrair 1 mês, resulta em 1 de dezembro de 1969). Tem uma explicação detalhada sobre esse comportamento [aqui nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/358583/112052) e opções de solução [nessa outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/383060/112052)

Comment: O formato não está correto para a função `strtotime`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado pessoal, deu certo

Comment: Responde a sua pergunta @FelipePacheco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certamente essa pergunta deve ter duplicatas, pois trabalhar com datas é sempre um problema para quem não as usa muito, eu mesmo as vezes me enrosco em algo, mas no caso do @FelipePacheco a solução é simples:

**A data de referência**

```
$dtini = '16/09/2019';
```

**O problema na subtração**

Você encontra um problema para a função `strtotime()` como você colocou na questão, devido ao fato da variável `$dtini` estar formatada em um padrão diferente, mas que pra nós é o padrão comum, para resolvê-lo é simples:

**A solução**

Basta substituir as `/` por `-` usando uma função nativa do PHP chamada `str_replace()` assim:

```
str_replace("/","-",$dtini);
```

Por fim a subtração ficará da seguinte forma:

```
echo //imprime na tela
    date('d/m/Y',//converte para o formato desejado
        strtotime('-1 month',//subtrai a data
            strtotime(//Converte a data 
                str_replace("/","-",$dtini)//Substitui as barras
            )
        )
    );
```